# C++: cannot assign index to iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Okay, a small problem with, hopefully, a quick, simple solution.

In my school textbook, in a chapter about the STL, it gives a simple sample program to input for using lists and for using an iterator with a list, like so:

```
#include <list> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;  

int main() 
{  
    list<int> myIntList;   

    // Insert to the front of the list.  
    myIntList.push_front(4);  
    myIntList.push_front(3);  
    myIntList.push_front(2);  
    myIntList.push_front(1);   

    // Insert to the back of the list.  
    myIntList.push_back(5);  
    myIntList.push_back(7);  
    myIntList.push_back(8);  
    myIntList.push_back(9);   

    // Forgot to add 6 to the list, insert before 7.  But first  
    // we must get an iterator that refers to the position  
    // we want to insert 6 at.  So do a quick linear search       
    // of the list to find that position.    
    list<int>::iterator i = 0;  
    for( i = myIntList.begin(); i != myIntList.end(); ++i )   
        if( *i == 7 ) break;        

    // Insert 6 were 7 is (the iterator I refers to the position        
    // that 7 is located.  This does not overwrite 7; rather it       
    // inserts 6 between 5 and 7.  
    myIntList.insert(i, 6);   

    // Print the list to the console window.  
    for( i = myIntList.begin(); i != myIntList.end(); ++i )   
        cout << *i << " ";   cout << endl; 
}
```

Now, at the line that says

```
list<int>::iterator i = 0;
```

I get an error in VS 2015 that says:

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from"int" to "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List simple_types<int>>>"
```

What is the problem with the code presented, what is the solution, and why is this a problem to begin with? <-(I'll even settle with a simple grammatical error).

Comment: "In my school textbook" wow. [Consider getting a better one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `std::list` does not have a random access iterator like e.g. `std::vector`

Comment: If the school textbook had this line: ***list<int>::iterator i = 0;*** I agree you need a better book..

Comment: drescherjm: Everything in the textbook has been fine up to now.

Comment: Note that this will not work even with vector (like "`vector<int>::iterator i = 0`")

Comment: Geez guys, it was just a typo, I don't think that warrants the "get a better book" comments, especially since we don't even know what book is actually being used.  Just remove the `= 0` from the iterator declaration and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the problem with the code presented

A simple typo in the example.

> what is the solution

Replace this line:

```
list<int>::iterator i = 0;
```

With this instead:

```
list<int>::iterator i;
```

> why is this a problem to begin with?

You cannot initialize an iterator with an integer value.  Only the container knows what its iterators refer to, so only the container can initialize them.  All you can do is request an iterator from a container, assign an iterator to another iterator, and increment/decrement/dereference an iterator.  That is all.

Answer (score 3):

The value `0` may not be a valid value for an iterator.  Try either removing the assignment or assigning the iterator to `myIntList.begin()`.

The iterator may not be able to be treated as an index, like with a `vector` or array.  Usually linked lists are not accessed by index; you have to traverse from the beginning.

Comment: You are right, however, you did not explain why `0` may not be a valid value for an iterator. If I am not mistaken, is it because `std::list` does not have random access iterator unlike from e.g. `std::vector`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, an integer is not a valid value for (any) iterator, because to construct an iterator, you need to somehow refer the original structure (where you get the iterator from). And this is clearly not the case with a simple integer. (or of course without arguments you create an invalid empty iterator)

Comment: There may not be a constructor or assignment operator that takes an integer value.

Comment: According to cppreference.com, the [`std::list::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) only has to satisfy the *Bidirectional Iterator* interface.

Comment: The code in the book may have been tested on an old compiler and library in which the list::iterator was a typedef for some sort of pointer. In that case, 0 would have been ok and synonymous to the null pointer.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: it makes sense that a `std::vector` iterator might be implemented using a raw pointer to the vector data, but a `std::list` iterator could never be implemented as a raw pointer, since pointer arithmetic on a list node pointer would not iterate the list correctly (unless the nodes are stored in contiguous memory, which `std::list` is not guaranteed to use). Iteration requires access to each node's inner pointers, and so a list  iterator would have to use a specialized class to handle the `++` and `--` operators correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you have a point - list::iterator wouldn't be a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/:

> An iterator is any object that, pointing to some element in a range of elements (such as an array or a container), has the ability to iterate through the elements of that range using a set of operators (with at least the increment (++) and dereference (*) operators).

This means that an iterator should be able to do the following:

1. Return the object it's currently "pointing" to (using the `*` operator)
2. Change itself to "point" to the next object in its list (using the `++` operator)

A reason for the existence of the iterator as a data type is to create a general way of interacting with different kinds of lists.  However, this means that different lists will implement their iterators differently.

In many circumstances, initializing an iterator to a number doesn't make sense because of the implementation under the hood.  As a result, we don't define an assignment operator with our iterator type `std::vector<int>::iterator` on the left and an `int` on the right.  So when you try to assign your iterator to an integral value, `list<int>::iterator i = 0;` your compiler throws an error.

Let's look at an example where assigning an iterator to `0` doesn't make sense.   You could implement an iterator for `std::vector<int>` as a pointer to an element in your vector.  In this case:

1. `*` dereferences the pointer stored in `vector<int>::iterator` and returns its value.
2. `++` modifies the pointer stored in `vector<int>::iterator` to point at the *next* element in the list.

However, assigning this pointer to `0` would be the same as assigning it to `NULL`, and dereferencing it no longer returns a valid element in your vector.  (In fact, dereferencing `NULL` will cause an error!)

To avoid this error, simply make sure that you always assign your iterator to a value of the same type.  In the STL, this is usually accomplished by using `.begin()` to return an iterator that points to the first element in your list.